# Jquery to create html tables with dictionaries entries in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm basically a javascript/html noob, please bear with me. Previously, I created an html table with jinja2. The row values were from a list of python key - value dictionary i.e.

```
rows = [{"category": "categoryA","region": "west", "count": 2},
        {"category": "categoryB","region": "east", "count": 3},
        {"category": "categoryC","state": "ny", "count": 3}]


{% for row in rows %}
 <tr>
  <td> {{row}} </td>
 </tr>    
{% endfor %}
```

which renders the column `details` as expected:

[image]

Currently, I'm working with ajax and want to create a similar table with jquery, but the values are not being parsed correctly:

```
html += '<tr>'
jQuery.each(rows, function(idx, row) {
   html += "<td>" + row + "</td>"
})
html += '</tr>';
```

the cells with the dict e.g. `{"category": "categoryC","state": "ny", "count": 3}` is rendered on the html table as `[object Object]`:

[image]

How to render such dictionary as values when creating the html table in JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `JSON.stringify()` to display like `string`

```
html += '<tr>'
jQuery.each(rows, function(idx, row) {
   html += "<td>" + JSON.stringify(row) + "</td>"
})
html += '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the same text representation of the object as before, try `JSON.stringify(row)`

Answer (score 1):

`[object Object]` is caused by a program outputting `Object.prototype.toString()` somewhere, you should use `JSON.stringify()` to make the objects appear as they shoudl:

```js
let rows = [{
    "category": "categoryA",
    "region": "west",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "category": "categoryB",
    "region": "east",
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "category": "categoryC",
    "state": "ny",
    "count": 3
  }
]

let html;

html += '<tr>'

$.each(rows, function(idx, row) {
  html += "<td>" + JSON.stringify(row) + "</td>"

})
html += '</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
        data = [{
            "name": "categoryA",
            "value": "west",
            "prop_type": 2
          },
          {
            "name": "categoryB",
            "value": "east",
            "prop_type": 3
          },
          {

            "name": "categoryC",
            "value": "ny",
            "prop_type": 3
          }
        ]


        object = JSON.parse(data),
                    array = Object.keys(object).map(function(k) {
                        return object[k];
                    });
                   var mainObj = array;
                   var k = '<tbody>'
                   for(i = 0;i < mainObj.length; i++){
                       k+= '<tr class="info">';
                       k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i].name + '</td>';
                       k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i].value + '</td>';
                       k+= '<td>' + mainObj[i].prop_type + '</td>';
                       k+= '</tr>';
                   }
                   k+='</tbody>';
                   document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = k;
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody id="tableData"></tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.